# What does “-z” does exactly in a shell script?

Tags: shell, if-statement, scripting, sh

I have got this script,I know what is happening in the first line and the if block, but cant understand the if condition.

```
pid5=$(ps aux | grep -w "consumer-1.0.jar general" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')

        if [ -z "$pid5" ]; then
            kill -9 "$pid5" 
        fi
```

I searched on google and SO too, but couldnt find any help.

Comment: That's a really brittle and roundabout way of writing `killall`, though. At the very least, the [useless `grep`s](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) should go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [man](http://ss64.com/bash/test.html) page it says:

> **`-z String'**
>
> ```
>  True if the length of String is zero.
> ```

Comment: Though that would be the manual of the `test` command; out of context, `-z` alone does nothing.

Comment: I was doing it wrong, I needed to check if string is non-empty .. i.e. i should have used -n.
thanks.